# Rebuild All Failed with 0 errors - Visual studio 2012 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have seen many post when I Google my issue but still the solution I get on the net doesn't help me much.

ISSUE - When I rebuild my project I get the message -

```
"Build FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped =========="
```

And on the error list there is no errors shown.

Please help and thank you in advanced.

Comment: Is there any more output in the Build Output tab?

Comment: Care to give links to the solutions you've tried? How do we know which ones you have/have not found and tried? We could end up either repeating advice you've already tried and failed with, or not posting advice because we assume you've already tried it.

Comment: Here is more output in in the build output tab - Error:  CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) - and I do have that namespace.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - the links as I said [its](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=Rebuild+All+Failed+with+0+errors&oq=Rebuild+All+Failed+with+0+errors&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.612j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=208&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @Lord-David - there is a difference between `using` directives and assembly references. Are you aware of this, and do you have *both*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

**Close all open files.**

**Clean your solution.**

**Close the Visual Studio**

**Rebuild the solution.**

Or this way

**1. In Solution Explorer, right-click on the Solution node and click Configuration Manager**

**2. Find your project and make sure Build is checked**

**3. Click Close**

and in your question there is an answer too as it shows 1 failed and you can see the desired output window with three tabs namely errors, warnings and messages..try to click them and find out what the error is?

Comment: Tried your first solution and Build is checked but still no success.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

If the tab isn't "orange" the errors are hidden, (its similar in vs2012).

Click on the error tab to see the errors

---

Further more, your actual error is that you haven't included a reference to `System.Web`, you may need to change your target framework to one that isn't a client profile (Project > --name here-- properties)

Comment: is the tab highlighted or not? (the one shown as ("1 error") on my image)

Comment: do the same for warnings and messages? I've had the same error before, either way, the fix is the same, your targeting the wrong framework

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem too and I figured out how to find the build error whatever it is. 
you should change the amount of detail the output window shows in Tools->Options in the setting below :

[image]

Since you change this setting the output window shows the build error and where it occurs.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today and fixed it by doing a repair.  `Start > Run > Appwiz.cpl > (Find your visual studio version) > right click > change > repair`
[image]